# crypto.subtle.importKey throws unspecified Error

Tags: javascript, certificate, digital-signature, smartcard, webcrypto-api

I'm trying to sign a text using **WEB Crypto API**. I'm depending on a 3rd party to extract the **certificate** from a smart card, which returns a Base64 string representation of it. As far as I understand, first I need to convert it to a **cryptoKey** object to pass it to the sign method and that is where the error occurs. [Here is how it looks in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2nVI.png).

Here is what I'm doing:

```
  const res = await fetch("https://localhost:53952/getsigner",{
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: "{}"
  })

const body = await res.json();
const signCertString = body.chain[0];

const binaryCert = Uint8Array.from(atob(signCertString), c => c.charCodeAt(0));
const certBuffer = binaryCert.buffer;

crypto.subtle.importKey(
  "pkcs8",
  certBuffer,
  {
    name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
    hash: { name: "SHA-256" },
  },
  true,
  ["sign"]
)
  .then((cryptoKey) => {
    console.log("CryptoKey object created:", cryptoKey);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error creating CryptoKey object:", error);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Uint8Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/from) only takes 1 argument, an array.

```js
Uint8Array.from(atob(signCertString), c => c.charCodeAt(0))
```

You probably meant to do something like this, to convert your decoded string into an array of char codes:

```js
Uint8Array.from([...atob(signCertString)].map(c => c.charCodeAt(0)))
```